# Where was "City Lights" shot?

Tags: film-location, city-lights

I watched *City Lights*, a very famous film by Charlie Chaplin. Where was the film shooting done? Is there any chance it was Lindsay street, Newmarket, Calcutta [kolkata]?

Comment: Given how extremely unlikely it is that it was shot there, is there anything that makes you *think* it was? In that case you might want to add that for some context.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson-A movie theater exists in calcutta[kolkata], and "Chaplin" is built in his memory. And the film location is very much like the new market, park street, and sudder street, Calcutta INDIA .thank you for correcting me.  user-37920

Comment: "Very much like"? Do you have photographs or screenshots that could make your speculation more convincing?

Answer (score 4):

It was shot in Los Angeles.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_Lights)...

> During this part of shooting, construction was being done at Chaplin Studios **because the city of Los Angeles had decided to widen La Brea Avenue** and Chaplin was forced to move several buildings away from the road.

And [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0021749/trivia?item=tr2550869)...

> Charles Chaplin spent $1,500,000 of his own money in making the film. **A river was built at Chaplin's studio**, which covered an area of five acres and cost $15,000 to construct. Two streets representing a downtown business section were also constructed at a cost of $100,000.

The set was a mad mix of cities, which could lead to the confusion. Again from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_Lights).

> Although the film was originally set in Paris, the art direction is inspired by a mix of several cities. Robert Sherwood said that "it is a weird city, with confusing resemblances to London, Los Angeles, Naples, Paris, Tangiers and Council Bluffs. It is no city on earth and it is all cities."

and

> Weissman also compared many of the film's sets with locations from Chaplin's real childhood, such as the statue in the opening scene resembling St. Mark's Church on **Kennington Park Road** and Chaplin referring to the waterfront set as the **Thames Embankment**.

Answer (score 1):

Both [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0021749/locations) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_Lights#Principal_photography) list *City Lights* as having been shot entirely in and around Los Angeles, California. There is no indication that any part of it was filmed outside the state, let alone outside the USA. Given that Chaplin was a Hollywood superstar, I would expect that if he *had* travelled to India to film, it would have made the news on both sides of the Pacific.

Answer (score -3):

I don't believe the film shot in Calcutta is a genuine Charles Chaplin film. The Calcutta film is shot around the new market area of Calcutta, which area is very famous, not only in INDIA but also in countries like the UK.
The Indian population that is INDIA became independent in 1947 after the independence struggle with the UK.So INDIA, CALCUTTA CITY, and Newmarket Calcutta are very well known to UK and Wales citizens.
Unfortunately, filmstar Charles Chaplin acted in the film as an agent of prostitutes. Perhaps he visited prostitute quarters, and the prostitutes are demanding ludicrous amounts. I will never forget him in that angry and hopeless mood. Apparently he was penniless, cursing.  Of course, The new market is the main center for prostitutes. He is a nice actor.
He is a comedian. I don't know the reason for showing him in an animation film. He is shown in that advertisement film he is polishing shoes.
How the film shot in Calcutta.A very low budget film Which is not genuine. Everybody will laugh that the new version of the movie cost 1.5 million dollars.  The movie theater showed "NEXT COMING-MODERN TIMES. I don't know whether the next coming film -MODERN TIMES is a genuine LOS ANGELES film or not. I was not fortunate enough to view "MODERN TIMES".But I can't agree with you that the Calcutta film is genuine and Charles Chaplin is also not fake. I have heard two or three adult very short duration films were added to attract the viewers. I am very sorry.

Answer (score -4):

I viewed the film "City lights" in 1979 in Calcutta.it appeared that the film is a low-budget film. The film with the same name-City lights, which was shot in Los Angeles, cost $1500000.I don't know whether the movie which was shot in Los Angeles is a costly remake of Charles Chaplin film-City lights. I think this is a sufficient cause for my confusion.

Comment: The film City-LIghts, which I viewed in Calcutta had a very old print, notwithstanding the fact that the film is excellent and marvellous. And the acting of Charles Chaplin is unique.

Comment: What about the version of City Lights you saw in 1979 makes you think it was low budget?

Comment: @JamesMcLeod-First of all the film is in black and white prints. nowadays Computers are used to complete a film, not only intimate scenes of main actors and actresses but even other actors, actresses also appear in front of movie cameras only for a while or little while.in locations that are very risky of sea, ocean, hills, computers are required to complete a movie. But in the very old film City lights, it appears pencil sketches or other outdated technics were used. I am sorry to make such comment even though the film is awesome and the acting of Charles Chaplin is incredibly exquisite.

Comment: Being in black and white is, well, pretty standard for 1931 when Chaplin made the movie. This in no way indicates low budget. I do not understand your point about using CGI in current films, and can’t recall anything like “pencil sketches,” unless you are referring to backdrops in some studio-filmed scenes. Naturally it uses techniques which have been superseded but this does not indicate a low budget either.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod-THE city lights mentioned are not inferior, even superior in an artistic, esthetic sense.No one can make such a film who has not mastery about film making. I had never gone to Los Angeles. But I wonder what a movie can be whose expenditures are $1500000. CGI-COMPUTER GENERATED IMAGERY, YES THAT'S THE POINT?FILM HERO IN THE FILM  IS NOT ALLOWED TOUCH THE HEROINE THANK YOU.YOU HAVE USED APPROPRIATE ABREVIATION. USER 37920

Comment: With inflation, that $US(1930) 1.5 million is over $US(2000) 23 million today. Is that really low-budget for a film from before stars commanded multi-million dollar salaries and post-production CGI can add huge costs?

Comment: @JamesMcLeod-I have understood your point.thankng you.I think there is no use going to chat user 37920.